# Angular UI Grid FooterCellTemplate not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I have some problems on my custom footer cell template.

[As you can see, some of the column footer templates are not showing up, I have identical implementation of footerCellTemplate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kx1Ci.png)

This is my ui grid columndef:

```
{ 
    name: 'TRAN_TYPE', 
    footerCellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">Total / Average</div>' 
},
{
    name: "ISSUED", 
    footerCellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">{{grid.appScope.Aggregator.AVG_CUST_TIME}}</div>'                
},
{ 
    name: 'SERVED', 
    footerCellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" style="background-color: Red;color: White">custom template</div>' 
},
{ 
    name: 'UNPROCESSED', 
    footerCellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" style="background-color: Red;color: White">custom template</div>' 
},
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think put (semicolon) `;` end of css attribute in SERVED and UNPROCESSED column

```
style="background-color: Red;color: White;"
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. However, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved it by refreshing the grid. Thanks for the responses!